# Android face detection

Tags: java, android

Can someone tell me if there is `Face detection` API for android? If so can someone share the link and any sample code that would help ?

Edit: I need to detect in real time (from the camera - like from a video)

Comment: See those questions in the bottom right hand corner? Try and see if they help.

Answer (score 1):

The android API provides a simple FaceDetector

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.Face.html

Comment: I thought this is used only for images ? Can this be used for video's as well ? Sorry, i am a newbie

Comment: @Illep No, it's just for Bitmaps

Comment: Do you know of any framework where i could identify face on a video ?

Comment: @Illep: have you found a solution? I'd like to do the same (face detection with position and all...) from the camera stream.

Comment: Sadly no, let me know if you find a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. http://www.Face.com   
 2. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.Face.html

***first  ::*** API allows third-party developers to create their own original apps that leverage our face recognition technology, algorithms, and database of tagged faces.

***second ::*** A Face contains all the information identifying the location of a face in a bitmap.

Comment: Sorry, i am a newbie. I need to detect faces after live capturing from a camera (Like from a video). I think the above 2 frameworks provides detection only for static images. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: you can also capture image and detect it because image will be store in sdcard so not at all problem that you can capture by camera or get from sdcard existed image.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Android) is pretty powerful and also available for Android. You may want to check it out. [This](http://www.stanford.edu/~zxwang/android_opencv.html) is a short introduction on how to use it.

Comment: This could detect faces of images and not from a video. I need to detect faces of a video.

Comment: Since a video is nothing else than a series of single frames, OpenCV can also be used to detect faces in a video. See this example: http://nashruddin.com/OpenCV_Face_Detection

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**FaceDetector**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html) class, and this is a basic example:

```
    public myView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        BitmapFactory.Options BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.threepoint_shooters_1990, BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo);
        imageWidth = myBitmap.getWidth();
        imageHeight = myBitmap.getHeight();
        myFace = new FaceDetector.Face[numberOfFace];
        myFaceDetect = new FaceDetector(imageWidth, imageHeight, numberOfFace);
        numberOfFaceDetected = myFaceDetect.findFaces(myBitmap, myFace);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        Paint myPaint = new Paint();
        myPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        myPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFaceDetected; i++) {
            Face face = myFace[i];
            PointF myMidPoint = new PointF();
            face.getMidPoint(myMidPoint);
            myEyesDistance = face.eyesDistance();
            canvas.drawRect((int) (myMidPoint.x - myEyesDistance * 2),
                    (int) (myMidPoint.y - myEyesDistance * 2),
                    (int) (myMidPoint.x + myEyesDistance * 2),
                    (int) (myMidPoint.y + myEyesDistance * 2), myPaint);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Download the full source code here:
**https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android_Face_Detection**