# Is there Face Recognition library inbuilt into Android IceCream?

Tags: android, face-detection

So `android.media.FaceDetector` exposes the android face detector to the application developer.

Is there a similar library for exposing Face Recognition inbuilt into Android IceCream ?

Comment: Please have a go at coming up with a better title rather than deliberately introducing a typo to get around the title duplicate filter.

Comment: This library isn't in IceCream?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android face detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132408/android-face-detection)

Comment: Face detection is NOT the same as face recognition. Detection is already in Android, that is being able to say **how many** faces are in an image. Recognition is actually **identifying** the faces (in the same way Picasa and Facebook do to tag people in pictures.)

Comment: Hi I know face detection is not face recognition otherwise I would not be asking the question. What I am asking is face recognition  exposed in the Android API ? Also I do not understand the problem with the title